# How to convert list of tuple to fixed key directory format in python

Tags: python, python-3.8

I tried to convert the below format of tuple

```
    [(1597209852, 'p'), ('o',1597209851)]
```

Into this :

```
    [  {"key":"p" ,"value": 1597209852  },{"key":"o" ,"value": 1597209851  }
```

This is my code but not working:

```
    po=[(1597209852, 'p'), (1597209851, 'o')]
    convertedlist = [dict(one=dd[0], two=dd[1])] for dd in po]
```

order is different in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description of the input and output, seems that all you need is:

```
def func(arr):
    return [{"key": item[1], "value": item[0]} for item in arr]
```

Answer (score 1):

is this what you were looking for?

```
po = [(1597209852, 'p'), (1597209851, 'o')]
newdict = {y:x for x, y in po}
```

output:

```
{'p': 1597209852, 'o': 1597209851}
```